# Type 'Context<{ ping: number; ready: true; }>' is not assignable to type 'Context'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, typescript-types

Here is my code. My default value should fit the type.

```
export interface ClientContextProps {
  ping: number  
  ready: boolean
}

export const ClientContext: React.Context<ClientContextProps> = createContext({
  ping: 0,
  ready: true 
})
```

[vscode language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2biS.png)

But it shows the following error in my vscode. It seems that the vscode treated "ready" as type **true** instead of type **boolean**.

```
Type 'Context<{ ping: number; ready: true; }>' is not assignable to type 'Context<ClientContextProps>'.

Types of property 'Provider' are incompatible.

Type 'Provider<{ ping: number; ready: true; }>' is not assignable to type 'Provider<ClientContextProps>'.

Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.

Type 'ProviderProps<ClientContextProps>' is not assignable to type 'ProviderProps<{ ping: number; ready: true; }>'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 1):

Type the call, not the variable type:

```js
export interface ClientContextProps {
  ping: number  
  ready: boolean
}

export const ClientContext = createContext<ClientContextProps>({
  ping: 0,
  ready: true 
})
```